# Why isn't the tree being printed?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I am trying to create a `Tree` class, I first started by creating a tree node class and then I began with making the tree module. The first method I'm trying to create is `print_tree`.

My strategy to traverse the tree is:

1. go to the child
2. go to the sibling if the node doesnt have children, else, go to the parent's sibling
3. break if the parent is `None` (that means that we are back to the root)

But it isn't working. Why?

```
class treeNode:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
        self.nextSibling = None
        self.level = 0

        def add_children(self,*child):
            for i in child:
                i.parent = self
                self.children.append(i)
                self.children[-1].nextSibling = i.data

        def level_func(self):
            itr = self
            count = 0
            while itr:
                count += 1
                itr = itr.parent
            self.level = count - 1

class Tree:
    def __init__(self,root:treeNode):
        self.root = root

    def print_tree(self):
        print(self.root.data)
        kid = self.root.children[0]
        while (kid != self.root):
            kid.level_func()
            print(" " * (3 * kid.level),kid.data)
            if len(kid.children) == 0:
                while kid.nextSibling is None or kid.parent is None:
                    kid = kid.parent
                else:
                    kid = kid.nextSibling
            else:
                kid = kid.children[0]

parent = treeNode(1)
child = treeNode(2)
parent.add_children(child,treeNode(3),treeNode(4),treeNode(5))
grand = treeNode(6)
child.add_children(grand,treeNode(7))
tree1 = Tree(parent)
tree1.print_tree()
```

Comment: I would expect that `self.root.parent` *is* `None`, as the root of the tree, by definition, has no parent.

Comment: @chepner what configurations should i make?

Comment: Ask yourself *why* you want `self.root.parent` to refer to a real node. Big hint: you should *not* be modifying `self.root` just to use it as a reference to some other node in the tree. `self.root` *is* the tree.

Comment: @chepner so i have to create an other variable for the children of the root and change it by each loop instead of doing that by self.root?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: @chepner nothing has changed

Comment: @chepner i think the problem is from the condition because it prints nothing

Comment: Your `while` loop is never being entered. Even if `self.root.parent` were not `None`, you initialized `count` to 0, so `count > 0` will be false. You can also try using `while True:`, then testing your condition in an `if` statement *after* the body executes once, using `break` to exit the loop. The key to debugging is to figure out where there is a problem, ask yourself *why* it is a problem, and make a change, then repeat. Eventually, you will identify all the problem spots and fix them.

Comment: @chepner i tried what you told me previously  and it started to become clear, also i fixed the loop condition, and now, i have an other problem, when i run it, it stops in the treenode(6), the interpreter tells me that kid has no attribute to level_func

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you link children as a linked list when they are already in a (standard) list? You should use one data structure for children, not two. So either stop using `nextSibling` or don't create a standard list.

Answer (score 0):

you should let the nodes handle the traversal with recursion. To print, implement the `__repr__()` method so that you can use print() directly on your tree nodes:

```
class treeNode:

    ...
    
    # list of lines to print for this node and its descendants 

    def lines(self,indent="",indent2=""): # node indent, children indent
        result = [indent+str(self.data)]       # line for node data
        for last,child in enumerate(self.children,1-len(self.children)):
            lines=child.lines(indent2+"|__ ",indent2+["|   ","    "][last==0]))
            result.extend(lines)               # add descendant lines
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join(self.lines())
```

Output:

```
parent = treeNode(1)
child = treeNode(2)
parent.add_children(child,treeNode(3),treeNode(4),treeNode(5))
grand = treeNode(6)
child.add_children(grand,treeNode(7))
parent.children[-1].add_children(treeNode(10))
tree1 = Tree(parent)

print(tree1.root)

1
|__ 2
|   |__ 6
|   |__ 7
|__ 3
|__ 4
|__ 5
    |__ 10

print(child)

2
|__ 6
|__ 7
```